# ScrollViewer not working horizontally on button click UWp

Tags: uwp, scrollviewer

I am trying it for two days but nothing worked for me. I am using `ScrollViewer` inside a `grid` in *UWP window 10*. What I am trying to do is to **scroll horizontally ob button click on both side of the `scrollviewer`**. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Below is my xaml code.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Background="#c71806" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" Click="Button_Click_1" >
    <Image Source="assets/leftArrow.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
  </Button>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="chkScrollViewer"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Width="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">

    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="84*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Button Click="openNewTablePopup" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" Width="150" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock x:Name="otherTb" Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">New Table</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
      <!--<Button  Width="150" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" Grid.Column="1" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
<StackPanel>
<Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
<TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Create Order</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Button>-->
      <Button Width="150"  Style="{StaticResource sddd}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="#093e7a" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnTimeClock_Click">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Assets/clockIcon_75x75.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Time Clock</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
      <Button Width="150"  Style="{StaticResource sddd}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnTransaction_Click">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="Assets/transaction_icon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Transaction</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
      <Button Width="150" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnsetting_Click">
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal" >Setting</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
      <Button Width="150" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="4" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnorderhistory_Click" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" >
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Order History</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

      <Button Width="150" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="5" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnmergeorder_Click" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" >
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Merge Table</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>

      <Button Width="150" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="6" Background="#093e7a" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="btnReports_Click" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" >
        <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="assets/newTableButtonIcon.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
          <TextBlock x:Name="lblreport" Foreground="#fff" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="Normal">Reports</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
    </Grid>

  </ScrollViewer>
  <Button Width="100" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="5" Background="#c71806" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource sddd}" Click="Button_Click" >
    <Image Source="assets/rightArrow.png" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
  </Button>

</Grid>
```

---

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    chkScrollViewer.ChangeView(3, null,null,true);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ScrollViewer not working horizontally on button click UWp

The problem is [`ChangeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview) method only using to change view with specified offsets. If you pass fixed `horizontalOffset`, it will scroll to the match position. if you want to scroll each time. you could refer the following.

```
private double horizontalOffset;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    horizontalOffset += 10;
    chkScrollViewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset, null, null, true);
}
```